# How to get JStree top level checked nodes.

Tags: jquery, jstree

I have created one jquery jstree using json object with check box. The tree is working fine. Now i need all the top level checked nodes (not their children). I have tried with below code which return me all the checked nodes including their childs.

```
$("#treename").jstree("get_checked",null,true).each

                          (function () { 

                     alert($(this).attr("path"));

 });
```

Refering to the below tree picture. I need only "CA_Administrator" not its child nodes like trunk,branch,tag.
[image: My Tree]

Comment: Any luck with this? I am facing the exact same problem with JStree 3 :(

Comment: @zaitsman Please follow my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just we need to change the parameter from true to false inside jstree function.

```
$("#treename").jstree("get_checked",null,false).each 

               (function () { 

               alert($(this).attr("path"));

               });
```

Comment: how to do this on the v3? theres only full objects true/false